# Transactions/Identity API must be enabled before using

Tags: actions-on-google

I have been trying to enable the streamline identity flown for google-actions. I have also set up a mocked Authorisation flow. I edited the fields in the actions console but I keep getting this error:

`expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0]: Transactions/Identity API must be enabled before using.`

I have tried from the simulator, from my phone, sandbox on and off, I still don't see what I need to activate to make it work.

Comment: I guess you checked "Does your app perform Transactions" in the Actions Console under Privacy and Consent?

Comment: aaaah! there we go! I was turning around the whole console thing I forgot this, I did the configuration one week ago... Thank you!

Comment: @NicoStrebel with that I could do ask for the account linking, but when it has got the token from my endpoint, the assistant seems blocked.
 The same endpoint works fine if i just do the account linking when launching the app.
I don't receive any request on my endpoints after it got the token, and when I restart the app the account is linked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Transactions API to enable streamlined account linking but you need it only to use the [mid-dialog account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#during_the_conversation) (AskForSignIn)

To test streamlined account linking without transactions API, you'll need to go to API.AI and select account linking required at the welcome intent. [Learn more here](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#account_linking_at_invocation_time).

Comment: yes I did but you still need to select "application is making transactions" in the actions console :)
Also it seems that the askForSignIn is having trouble, it is stuck in the assistant after getting the token, I don't receive the next intent request

Comment: Can you make sure you're using the latest version of the "Google search" app from the play store (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox)?

Comment: I am using the google assistant that came with Nougat update. I know this askForSignIn it is a Beta feature there might  be some problems is it working for anyone else?
It is working until the get the token and then just freeze. When I invoke my app again the requests have the token

Comment: Also note that the authentication works if i use the same sign in process when I tick "Sign in required for welcome intent". The only thing blocking is AskForSignIn

Comment: How does the app freeze? This might be a separate bug. If AskForSignIn didn't work, try installing the beta version of the Google search app: https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox then try again

Comment: -The app is writing 'linking account ...' and the icon of my app was like about to say something with the bubble and the  "..." [image](http://imgur.com/a/s0SqM)
-Then I tried to put the welcome intent as a required sign in intent, and when I click on link your account in the assistant, it is telling me that the app is not installed (???) .  
-I tried downloading the Beta, i don't see any different .

Comment: The "app is not installed" is a bug unfortunately, that we now fixed (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462967/app-isnt-installed-for-any-actions-app-that-requires-account-linking) Let me look into the image you're showing as it might be another bug and get back to you.

Comment: Were you using the public beta for the in-conversation account linking?

To summarize:
> In-conversation account linking only works with the public beta right now. Otherwise, it'll link the account but not resume the conversation (call your endpoint)
> Account linking had a bug last week, that is now fixed, telling users "app not installed". The bug should affect beta and prod versions of the app.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have not updated action package. Check if the information in the account linking is identical to that of your action package.