# "App isn't installed" for any Actions app that requires Account Linking

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm working on an Assistant app which requires account linking, and I've gotten to the step where, if I say "*talk to [my app name]*" I get back a card with the text "*Link [my app name] to Google*". Clicking it however only gives me an (improperly formatted) toast with the text "**App isn't installed**".

I thought I did something wrong, so I tested other apps that require account linking. Alarm.com, Mail Buddy, they all behave the same way. How is a user supposed to "install" these apps ?

Comment: I believe the actions API is under active development right now. I'm seeing this too, have been in touch with support, and even they seem confused as to how to get account linking working, and differences when testing across multiple surfaces. I do hope Google stabilizes things soon.

Comment: I am having this same issue, it was not a problem until very recently.

Comment: This is now fixed by Google!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a bug on Google side that is now fixed